# Kubernetes pods Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, nfs, deployment

I have a problem with MariaDB (mysqld.sock)
I have the next architecture:

1. Deployment for APP1
2. Deployment for MariaDB1
3. PV11 and PVC11 (/var/lib/mysql/), PV12 and PVC12 (/run/mysql/)
4. NFS1 server. Database and mysqld.sock save in NFS
5. Namespace1

From deployment MariaDB1 I get files DB and mysqld.sock saved in NFS server and than mounted to deployment for app1. The APP1 works well.
And I have exactly the same application 2 which does not work via the socket.
When I connect to MySQL via mysqld.sock from pod APP1 I have a connection.
But when I connect to MySQL via mysqld.sock from pod APP2 I have an error.
mysql -S /opt/mariadb-mysqld/mysqld.sock -u root -p ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/mariadb-mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBYTR.png)

Comment: Are you aware that unix sockets won't work across different hosts? And why would you even share /var/lib/mysql/ to the application? The application only needs a unix socket or a TCP socket to talk to MariaDB.